# Allow GitHub actions to merge PRs on protected branch

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, github-cli

I have configured my repository so that GitHub actions are able to approve PRs

[image: Screenshot 2022-11-01 at 11 44 10 AM]

I have branch protection rule, requiring 1 approval before merging.

[image]

However the following step fails

```
      - name: perform the merge if applicable
        env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        shell: bash
        run: |
            echo "Approving PR..."
            gh pr review --approve ${{ github.event.issue.number }}
            echo "Merging PR..."
            gh pr merge ${{ github.event.issue.number }} --admin --squash
```

(the PR is indeed approve but the merge fails)

```
Approving PR...
Merging PR...
Message: You're not authorized to push to this branch. Visit https://docs.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches/ for more information., Locations: [{Line:1 Column:58}]
```

How can I allow `github-actions` bot to also merge the PR?

#### update 1

after removing the `--admin` flag, just in case

```
Approving PR...
Merging PR...
X Pull request #199 is not mergeable: the base branch policy prohibits the merge.
To have the pull request merged after all the requirements have been met, add the `--auto` flag.
To use administrator privileges to immediately merge the pull request, add the `--admin` flag.
```

#### update 2

I have added the following permissions to the `GITHUB_ACTIONS` token, without any effect whatsoever

```
permissions:
 contents: write
 pull-requests: write
 repository-projects: write
```

Comment: Who is the creator of the pr you want to merge? The creator of a pr cannot approve his/her own pr - it the pr is created by an GH action, I guess it won't work.

Comment: The creator is me (not GH actions) and that's why `github-actions` bot is able to approve it (but for some reason, not to merge it)

Comment: Have you tried to remov the `--admin` flag from the `gh pr merge` command? As far as I know, GH action cannot perform admin tasks with their default GH_TOKEN.

Comment: just tried it. check my update in the question

Comment: Okey, great. I guess the first "permission denied" was related to the admin flag. As I cannot the the requirements you defined, could it be the case, that there are still required action running like for liniting or testing? Have you tried the `--auto` flag?

Comment: turns out `--auto` and `--admin` cannot be combined `specify only one of `--auto`, `--disable-auto`, or `--admin``

Comment: Sure, please try only the `--auto` flag. In addition, what requirements do you have set for the branch policy?

Comment: disallowing direct pushes to the protected branch; I wouldn't expect this to affect it, since **it is not a direct push**

Answer (score 0):

The default `GITHUB_TOKEN` doesn't have admin rights. You need to change it with a custom token of the user with admin rights.

Example:

```
    jobs:
      Merge_PR_Example:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest

        permissions:
          contents: write
          pull-requests: write
          repository-projects: write

        env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ADMIN_RIGHTS_TOKEN }}

        steps:
          - uses: actions/checkout@v3

          - name: Merge PR
            run: gh pr merge ${{ github.event.issue.number }} --admin --squash
            env:
              GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ADMIN_RIGHTS_TOKEN }}
```

Select all `repo` and `wrokflow` scopes for the token. These are enough.

[image: Selected scopes for the token]